# How Could I Get the Window Title from Its Process Name?

Tags: c++, process

This is my code to check if the process name existed or not:

```
bool isRunning (LPCSTR processname)
{
    HANDLE Snapshot;
    Snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if(Snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 ProcessEntry;
        BOOL           Succeed;
        ProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        Succeed = Process32First(Snapshot, &ProcessEntry);

        while(Succeed)
        {
          if(lstrcmp(ProcessEntry.szExeFile,processname) == 0)
          {
           return true;
          }
      Succeed = Process32Next(Snapshot, &ProcessEntry);
    }

    CloseHandle(Snapshot);
    }
}
```

How could I use it or edit it to get the window title from its process name (for example "notepad.exe")?
If it existed the program would return text like "New text document - Notepad"

Comment: Process => threads => EnumThreadWindows().  Usually a process has only one thread that creates windows, it is however not a rule.  And of course a thread can create multiple windows, there is no rule which one of those is the "main" window.  So you can make this work for a *specific* program that has well defined behavior, certainly for Notepad, it is not a universal approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually addressed in [Microsoft's description of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx).

It says "You can use the [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) function to retrieve the full name of an executable image for both 32- and 64-bit processes from a 32-bit process."

You'll basically need to iterate through checking your `HANDLE`s with `QueryFullProcessImageName`.

Comment: Doesn't the question request the Window Title, and not the executable name?